# Can ios/build folder be ignored in a React-Native project?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on a project alone but soon I'll be working with other people on my React-Native project and everytime I commit changes, there's A LOT of files that changed in this folder and I'm afraid this could cause a lot of problems if I were to work with a team on this project. Can I add this folder to my .gitignore file without having any problems? Also the size of this folder is very huge, something like 537Mb so far.

Side question: is the content of this folder generated by React-Native when it compiles the whole project?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore this folder, it's generated every time you build a project

Here is safe list which you can add to .gitignore to ignore xcode unnecessary files:

```
# Xcode
#
build/
Pods/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace
```

Also you can clean project if it comes to that big size:

(Product -> Clean or CMD+Shift+K)